# How to add a 'colorbar' and set 'clim' to a colour image overlaid on a grey level image?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I am trying to overlay a colour image on a grey level image. However, when I try to plot the 'colorbar' and set the 'clim'. Matlab always produce a colorbar according to the underneath grey level image.

However, I want to get the colorbar for the overlaid colour image. Any suggestions would be appreciate. Thanks a lot.

```
%% Example codes:
  greyImage = imread('AT3_1m4_08.tif');
  colorImage = imread('hestain.png');

  figure,

  greyImagePlot = image(greyImage); colormap(gray); hold on;

  overlayImage = imagesc(colorImage, ...
      'CDataMapping', 'scaled', 'HitTest', 'off');
  alF = 0.5.*ones(size(colorImage, 1), size(colorImage, 2));
  set(overlayImage, 'AlphaData', alF);
  colorbar; % This will show a grey scale colorbar not the colour one I want
  set('CLim', [0 100]); % Also, the colormap limit here is not working

  axis off          
  axis image
```

Answer (score 3):

A reference for single figure/multiple colormaps can be found here
http://www.mathworks.fr/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html

Using images in particular, one can use 'subimage' function.

I also use 'FreezeColor' and 'cbfreeze' functions from 'matlabcentral' when a home-made solution is too tricky.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors-unfreezecolors
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24371

A straightforward - and lazy - solution for keeping a colorbar across multiple plots within the same axes: first plot the colour image and its colorbar, freeze the colorbar, then plot over the grey level image (no transparency), and finally plot the colour image again (transparency).

Here is a piece of code.

```
figure;

%first step: RGB image and colorbar
overlayImage = imagesc(colorImage, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled', 'HitTest', 'off');
alF = 0.5.*ones(size(colorImage, 1), size(colorImage, 2));
set(overlayImage, 'AlphaData', alF);
colorbar; 
set(gca, 'CLim', [0 100]); 

cbfreeze; %from 'COLORMAP and COLORBAR utilities' in Matlab Central

%second step: gray image (no transparency)
greyImagePlot = image(greyImage); colormap(gray); hold on;

%third step: plot colour image
overlayImage = imagesc(colorImage, ...
  'CDataMapping', 'scaled', 'HitTest', 'off');
alF = 0.5.*ones(size(colorImage, 1), size(colorImage, 2));
set(overlayImage, 'AlphaData', alF);

axis off          
axis image
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first method ColorMap = get(gcf,'Colormap') still get the colormap for the underneath grey level image, not the coloured one overlaid.

Really not sure how to use FreezeColor.

Comment: Yes, could you please provide some codes or extension of the current example to show that the reference page you mentioned is really working to display the colarbar of the overlaid colour image?

Comment: @Samo Jerom, could you please provide a follow up by either accepting the answer or giving a more detailed description of the answer you are expecting? Many thanks!